# Binding child class into parent class in css

Tags: css

So, I have divs as following:

```
<div class="first">
   <div class="second">
      <div class="third">
         <div class="fourth">

         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

For css, I wan to include "Second", "third" and "fourth" inside of "first" like below (but obviously not correct).

```
.first{
  .second{some css}
  .third{some css}
  .fourth{some css}
}
```

What is the proper way of binding inner class into a top class without repeating the top class?

Comment: I don't think nesting classes is possible in regular css3 - but sass allows it, which is exactly why developers use sass. Is there a reason you can't use @tR4xX 's  answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SASS.

In SASS you can do this:

```
nav {
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }

  li { display: inline-block; }

  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

[SASS Official Page](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

Comment: Why the downvote? Pretty sure this is exactly the right answer!

Comment: Thank you for the useful info! :) I upvoted your answer! =)